# Reading in csv with multi-col and multi-index

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read in a csv with the following first rows:

```
,,,,price,price,units,units
,,,,mean,mom_2,mean,mom_2
"('desc', 'foo')","('desc', 'bar')","('desc', 'year')","('desc', 'month')",,,,
```

The first row is supposed to be the top level of the multi-column. That makes sense because they're groups (price, units). For some reason, the third row has the multi-index in tuples: the layers are in (top, bottom) format.

My naive approach naturally did not work:

```
pd.read_csv(fileName, index_col=[0, 1, 2, 3], header=[0, 1])
```

gives me something like

```
                                                                                    price  \
                                                                                     mean   
('desc', 'foo') ('desc', 'bar') ('desc', 'year') ('desc', 'month')             
1200000110      13.0                         2010             1                  1.430365   
                                                              2                  1.446855
```

Neither did

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)
```

Is there some nice way to re-create the MultiIndex from the tuples as I have them now?

Comment: Can you add the expected output ?

Comment: @Shijo I think the expected output is a multi-index with `desc` being the top level, and `foo`, `bar`, `year` and `month` being the second level, instead of the tuple mix we see right now